# Strange margin between image and border

Tags: css, margin

I have simple html:

```
<div class="other-album">
   <a href="#"> <img src="https://pravdamuzika.lasil.ru/media/files/covers/2021_8_13__Panimonica_Offline_Oblozhka.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.other-album img{
width: 332px;
height: 332px;
border: #156196 solid 5px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

It looks perfect. But if I zoom it in browser I see strange margin between image and its border. And place of that margin depends on zoom degree

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/ishayahu/d51zjrkp/1/

Comment: I think it is because img is an inline element, try to add display:inline-block; to the img

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the box-sizing property to your image.

```
.other-album img{
width: 332px;
height: 332px;
border: #156196 solid 5px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
box-sizing: border-box; // solves your issue
}
```

Or if the anchor is already a display inline-block you may need to add font-size: 0;

Comment: I updated fiddle, but I still see that problem

Comment: Did you also click run? it won't auto-update. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, I have no idea why that happens or how to stop it from happening in this case. But I found a workaround (at least for chrome) - Don't use `<img>`, set background to the `<a>` instead!

```html
<div class="other-album">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

```css
.other-album a {
    width: 332px;
    height: 332px;
    border: #156196 solid 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("https://pravdamuzika.lasil.ru/media/files/covers/2021_8_13__Panimonica_Offline_Oblozhka.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oj7cf021/4/

Comment: thanks, it works, but it's not a good way, because i need mix data and representation. But one more time thank you!